# Перегрузка операций и приоритет

Tags: c++

Имеется три объекта одного класса с перегруженными операциями + и *. Сохранят ли эти операции приоритет или нет? Почему? 
Например:

```
rezult = a + b * c.
```

Где a, b, c - объекты одного класса. Какая будет последовательность выполненных операций и почему?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В С и С++ приоритет операций диктуется грамматикой языка и наследуется из грамматики языка. Грамматике языка не интересно, встроенные ли это операторы или перегруженные.

Приоритет операций в общем случае не имеет никакого отношения к последовательности выполнения операторов. Но именно для *перегруженных* операторов такая связь имеется - перегруженные операторы выполняются именно в порядке их приоритета.

Если считать, что все операторы в данном выражении перегружены, то сначала будет выполнено умножение `b * c`, затем сложение `a + ...`, и затем - присваивание `result = ...`.

Comment: "_Приоритет операций в общем случае не имеет никакого отношения к последовательности выполнения операторов_" Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: @wololo Именно это и имею в виду. Для встроенных операторов порядок их выполнения никак не диктуется их приоритетом или ассоциативностью. Более того, то, что будет фактически выполняться, в общем случае не обязано соответствовать тому, что написано в исходномкоде. Результат должен быть правильным - но не более того.

Comment: Результат должен быть правильным — это значит, что результат должен быть таким, как если бы встроенные операторы выполнялись в порядке, соответствующем их приоритету и ассоциативности?